# Prove equivalence relation for differentiable functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

I'm working (solo) through Thomas Judson's [Abstract Algebra](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-sets-and-equivalence-relations.html) and I'm looking at Example 1.22. I'd like to know whether my proof is complete (it differs from his):

### Problem

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions on $\mathbf{R}$. Define $\sim$ as $f(x) \sim g(x)$ if $f'(x) = g'(x)$. Prove that $\sim$ satisfies the properties of an equivalence relation.

### My Proof

#### Reflexivity

> Need to prove $f(x) \sim f(x)$:

$f'(x) = f'(x)$, so $f(x) \sim f(x)$

#### Symmetry

> Need to prove $f(x) \sim g(x) \Rightarrow g(x) \sim f(x)$):

If $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then $f'(x) = g'(x)$

Then $g'(x) = f'(x)$ and therefore $g(x) \sim f(x)$

#### Transitivity

> Need to prove $f(x) \sim g(x) \space and \space g(x) \sim h(x) \Rightarrow f(x) \sim h(x)$

If $f(x) \sim g(x)$, then $f'(x) = g'(x)$

If $g(x) \sim h(x)$, then $g'(x) = h'(x)$

$f'(x) = g'(x) = h'(x)$, so $f'(x) = h'(x)$, so $f(x) \sim h(x)$

Are there any problems with this proof? In the book (viewable at the link above) Judson says "it is clear that $\sim$ is both reflexive and symmetric and he gives a different, more difficult to understand (in my opinion) proof of transitivity. It makes me think my proof might be missing something...

Comment: This is fine. There may be many ways to prove something.

Comment: You may want to see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488574/718671) to another question on equivalence relations. I prove a more general phenomenon, which turns out to encompass yours (take $A$ the set of differentiable functions, $B$ its image under differentiation, $f$ to be the derivative operator, $R$ to be equality).

Comment: Your proof is better than his. Note that by the same proof $f \sim g$ if $\Phi(f) = \Phi(g)$ is always an equivalence relation, if $\Phi$ is any mapping. It turns out that any equivalence relation can be defined this way. In your case, the mapping is $\Phi: f \mapsto f'$

Comment: The wording of this problem is confusing. I find the wording of the URL to be more clear and precise. The wording here sounds like "Prove that $f \sim g$ holds whenever $f'$ and $g'$ satisfy some equivalence relationship" (which leaves the meaning of $f \sim g$ undefined).  I was completely confused that three commenters above could even make sense of the question.  Then I realized you really are trying to **define** $f \sim g$ to mean that $f'=g'$.

Comment: @Michael I've adjusted the wording to hopefully make this more clear.